# Implementing an interface provided by a Client

Tags: java, interface, client, final

I have following task

```
public class Event {

    private final Integer id;
    private final Collection<Market> market;
    private final Boolean completed;

    public Event(Integer id,
            Collection<Market> market, Boolean completed) {
        this.id = id;
        this.market = market;
        this.completed = completed;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Boolean getCompleted() {
        return completed;
    }
}

public class Market {


    private final Integer marketId;


    public Market(Integer marketId) {
        this.marketId = marketId;
    }

    public Integer getMarketId() {
        return marketId;
    }
}

public interface Client
{

    public void addEvent(Event event);

    /**
     * Update event status to completed. 
     */
    public void eventCompleted(Integer id);

    /**
     * Add market to an existing event
     */
    public void attachMarketToEvent(Integer id, Market market);

    /**
     * Remove market from an existing event
     */
    public void removeMarketFromEvent(Integer id, Market market);
}
```

I need to implement the client without changing the Event or Market classes.
How to make it? Any ideas? I could implement it but if I change this final fields.
What is expected from me? I am really surprised.

Comment: What is expected is of us? If you don't know what is expected of you, can you ask someone about it? That being said, it looks like the only final field that really needs to be modified by the `Client` is the `completed` flag.

Comment: maybe this is some kind of pattern or something .. I dont know this is the task.

Comment: As, ChetanKinger said there's lack of info in your question.

Can you copy the whole task, may be you are missing something?

Comment: @naskobg13 can you check the following line of code? `this.marketRefTypes = market;`I believe it has a mistake before even if you create a MarketRefType class that implements Collection<Market> it would still not be compatible with market which is of Collection<Market>

Comment: I corrected it @alainlompo

Comment: @naskobg13, thanks! How about this method's signature in the Client interface? `public void eventCompleted(Integer id)`? to me it should be boolean instead of void? It seems to me the goal is to check and see if the event with the given Id has been completed or not. Can you check it also please?

Comment: @alainlompo the method public void eventCompleted(Integer id) is exactly like that ! The goal is to make the event completed !!! Also it is written "Once an Event has completed, it is no longer of any relevance to the client."

Comment: I added the implementation of Market class also

Comment: @alainlompo It's clear from the code comments that `eventCompleted` is going to update the status of the event to completed.

Comment: this is all the information I  have and  I cannot ask questions ....

Comment: @naskobg13 I have explained in my answer that the only problem in implementing a `Client` is the `eventCompleted` method. Rest of the methods are correct. Do you need any more clarification other than my answer?

Comment: @naskobg13 If you can't ask a question, then this question does not belong on stackoverflow.com. It is a better fit for workplace.stackexchange.com. The quesiton should be worded `What to do when asked to work on a task and asking questions is not allowed`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76470/discussion-between-naskobg13-and-chetan-kinger).

Comment: @naskobg13 you also need to add a getter to your  `private final Collection<Market> market;`otherwise since it is private and not even protected, no external class can access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Event` is immutable. That is, it cannot be changed once it has been created. Looking at the `Client` interface, the only method that seems to be posing a problem is the `eventCompleted` method :

```
    /**
     * Update event status to completed. 
     */
    public void eventCompleted(Integer id);
```

Looks like this method expects you to update the `completed` flag of an `Event` to true which is not possible.

The rest of the methods won't be a problem because they don't modify the fields of `Event` :

1. `addEvent(Event event)`  : This shouldn't be a problem since a new Event can always be created
2. `attachMarketToEvent(Integer id, Market market)` and `removeMarketFromEvent(Integer id, Market market)` : These shouldn't be a problem because they will be used to add new objects to the `market` collection which is allowed.

You need to go back to whoever is expecting you to implement the client and ask them : How do I update the `completed` field if `Event` is immutable?